# using setOnItemClickListener and new intent not working

Tags: java, android, gridview, onitemclick

I have a grid view with images in it. Once one is clicked it should go to `PlayVideoActivity` but `onItemClick` never get called.

I followed in the debugger and tried clicking the image but it never fired `onItemClick`.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_videos);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    customGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.row_grid,
            getData());

    gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {

            Toast.makeText(videoChannelActivity.this, i + "#Selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(videoChannelActivity.this, PlayVideoActivity.class);
            startActivity(myIntent);

        }
    });
}
```

row_grid.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/grid_color_selector"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="158dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
    android:scaleType="centerInside" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12sp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: show me your `row_grid.xml` file

Comment: ok try to add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to your main layout

Comment: 1+ @simpleplan for responding correctly within 5min. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` attribute in parent layout of `row_grid.xml`

Answer (score 0):

You should remove

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

Comment: Thank! that and android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" did it